# Scheduling an email to send in mail (mac)

Tags: macos, email, applescript

I have an email that I need to schedule to send later. I know you can schedule an apple script to fire off at a set time using iCal, but I have been unable to find one that works. It doesn't necessarily have to be done this way though. I would be grateful of a solution to this problem.

Comment: Um, `iCal` already lets you do this - click on the `alert` popup in an event and select `Email`.

Comment: I believe this just sends you a reminder email, It doesn't send emails that you have written.

Comment: OK - you might want to make that part of your question a bit more explicit then.

Comment: Thunderbird has a "[Send Later](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/send-later-3/)" add-on that works fairly well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting an error like `outgoing message 1 doesn’t understand the send message` when trying to send an outgoing message. Referring to a message created from a script still seems to work though.

```
tell application "Mail"
    set m to make new outgoing message with properties {subject:"subject", content:"content"}
    tell m
        make new to recipient at end of to recipients with properties {address:"jana@doe.com, john@doe.com"}
    end tell
    send m
end tell
```

You could also [create a Calendar alarm in Automator](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45604/how-can-i-send-a-mail-message-later).

[image]

Comment: cool Ive almost got it to work, but I have multiple people who I need to send it to. My apple script is rubbish at best. Don't suppose you could tell me how to do this? cheers for all your help

Answer (score 0):

This works for me with a run script alarm in iCal on 10.6.8

```
tell application "Mail"
    activate
    set mymail to make new outgoing message at the beginning of outgoing messages with properties {subject:"Triggered"}
    tell mymail
        make new to recipient at beginning of to recipients with properties {address:"first@email.com, second@email.com"}
        set content to "hi"
    end tell
    --show message window (otherwise it's hidden)
    set visible of mymail to true
    --bring Mail to front
    activate
    send mymail
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

I just accomplished this without Automator, using only Apple Mail:

1. Double-click anywhere your calendar to start creating an event.
2. Give the event a name. This will be the subject line of the email.
3. Set the date and time of the event to when you want the email to be sent.
4. If you want the email to be sent on a schedule, choose a repeat frequency and potential termination date.
5. For the `alert`, choose `Custom...`.

[image]

6. Select `email`. You might be prompted to add a contact card to the Contacts app.

[image]

7. Choose the person to whom you want to send the email, and set the time to `At Time Of Event`. Press `OK`.

[image]

8. You can choose to add Notes, a URL, or attachments. I haven't tried these options, but I assume that they are carried forward in the email that is sent.

[image]